# Firebase Data from Google Analytics API

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

How can we get firebase data via Google Analytics API?
Normally, APP data was on Google Analytics property, and it was possible to get data via Google Analytics View ID. 
Unfortunately, Google supposes app tracking on Firebase now. How we can get firebase data via Google Analytics API (core api) on Google sheets?

Comment: nope, and currently there is no Firebase Reporting API.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you're asking for, but if you have the "Blaze" Firebase plan it's possible to export Firebase Analytics and other data to BigQuery to allow querying the raw data.

> 1. Sign in to Firebase.
> 2. Click the Settings icon and select Project Settings.
> 3. On the Project Settings page, click the Integrations tab.
> 4. On the BigQuery card, click Link.
> 5. If billing has not already been enabled for your project, click
>      Upgrade & link.

Further reading:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery